# Webdriver - java - how to release keys after performing an action

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using a webdriver [Action](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) to perform some keys combinations:

```
new Actions(getWebDriver()).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, ..).perform();
```

My problem is that the `Keys.CONTROL` remains activated after the action is performed. And after some new clicks, I have new opened tabs on my browser and strange behaviors due to fact that the key is still activated. How to release the key? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up a series of actions and then perform them. A useful demonstration of how to release the control key is to remove the *Add-on bar* by simulating a <kbd>Control+/</kbd> keypress then subsequently sending a `keyUp` message to release the held <kbd>Control</kbd> key:

```
WebDriver driver = getDriver();
String handle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Remove the "add-on" bar.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
Actions actions = new Actions( driver );
actions
  .sendKeys( Keys.CONTROL, Keys.DIVIDE )
  .keyUp( Keys.CONTROL )
  .build()
  .perform();

// Return back to whatever window was first selected.
driver.switchTo().window( handle );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Keys.chord()`. Per the [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#chord%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29):

> Simulate pressing many keys at once in a "chord". Takes a sequence of
>   Keys.XXXX or strings; appends each of the values to a string, and adds
>   the chord termination key (Keys.NULL) and returns the resultant
>   string. Note: When the low-level webdriver key handlers see Keys.NULL,
>   active modifier keys (CTRL/ALT/SHIFT/etc) release via a keyup event.

So the `Keys.NULL` that is automatically appended using a chord should release control.

**Solution**

```
new Actions(getWebDriver()).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, ...)).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

for me only such workaround helped:

```
new Actions(selenium).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
```