# Selenium keys.chord does not release control keys

Tags: firefox, selenium

This code selects two textboxes because it seems the control key is not released.

```
findElement('#textbox-wrapper').click();
findElement('#textbox').sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "A"))
findElement('#textbox2-wrapper').click();
```

If I comment out the middle line, it selects the text boxes sequentially, leaving the second one selected at the end of the test as expected.

If I comment out both clicks and manually press f on the browser window after the sendKeys, it performs a Ctrl+F find so it would appear the sendKeys is definately not releasing ctrl.

Interestingly, sending another key `findElement('#textbox').sendKeys("A")` seems to fix the issue, as clicking or pressing f after that no longer acts as if ctrl is held down.

The selenium documentation seems to suggest an existing issue

[Note: When the low-level webdriver key handlers see Keys.NULL, active modifier keys (CTRL/ALT/SHIFT/etc) release via a keyup event. Issue: http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/issues/detail?id=79](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)

but that link is broken...

Selenium 2.3
Firefox 23

Give.

*Update*

Found these:

http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/Release-ctrl-key-using-Actions-td25378.html

[Webdriver - java - how to release keys after performing an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311513/webdriver-java-how-to-release-keys-after-performing-an-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround solution if anyone happens to stumble upon the same problem.
I couldn't make the webdriver release the control keys so I'm making the robot release any pressed control keys after every sendkey. Generated using sublime text, pleasure to use.

```
    /**
     * Give a sequence of characters, will find control keys and use the java awt robot to keyRelease these control keys.
     * The firefox web driver doesn't release control keys properly causing subsequent actions to be performed with these
     * keys still pressed.
     */
    private void RobotReleaseKeys(CharSequence[] charSequences) throws AWTException {
        Robot rob = new Robot();
        for (CharSequence charSequence: charSequences) {
            for (char c: charSequence.toString().toCharArray()) {
                if (c == Keys.CONTROL.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                } else if (c == Keys.DELETE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
                } else if (c == Keys.END.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);
//                } else if (c == Keys.NULL.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NULL);
                } else if (c == Keys.CANCEL.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CANCEL);
                } else if (c == Keys.HELP.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HELP);
                } else if (c == Keys.BACK_SPACE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
                } else if (c == Keys.TAB.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                } else if (c == Keys.CLEAR.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CLEAR);
//                } else if (c == Keys.RETURN.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RETURN);
                } else if (c == Keys.ENTER.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                } else if (c == Keys.SHIFT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
//                } else if (c == Keys.LEFT_SHIFT.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_SHIFT);
                } else if (c == Keys.CONTROL.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
//                } else if (c == Keys.LEFT_CONTROL.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_CONTROL);
                } else if (c == Keys.ALT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
//                } else if (c == Keys.LEFT_ALT.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_ALT);
                } else if (c == Keys.PAUSE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE);
                } else if (c == Keys.ESCAPE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                } else if (c == Keys.SPACE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                } else if (c == Keys.PAGE_UP.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP);
                } else if (c == Keys.PAGE_DOWN.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
                } else if (c == Keys.END.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);
                } else if (c == Keys.HOME.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
                } else if (c == Keys.LEFT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                } else if (c == Keys.ARROW_LEFT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                } else if (c == Keys.UP.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                } else if (c == Keys.ARROW_UP.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                } else if (c == Keys.RIGHT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                } else if (c == Keys.ARROW_RIGHT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                } else if (c == Keys.DOWN.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                } else if (c == Keys.ARROW_DOWN.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                } else if (c == Keys.INSERT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_INSERT);
                } else if (c == Keys.DELETE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
                } else if (c == Keys.SEMICOLON.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                } else if (c == Keys.EQUALS.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD0.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD1.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD2.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD3.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD4.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD5.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD6.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD7.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD8.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8);
                } else if (c == Keys.NUMPAD9.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9);
                } else if (c == Keys.MULTIPLY.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY);
                } else if (c == Keys.ADD.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ADD);
                } else if (c == Keys.SEPARATOR.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEPARATOR);
                } else if (c == Keys.SUBTRACT.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
                } else if (c == Keys.DECIMAL.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL);
                } else if (c == Keys.DIVIDE.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE);
                } else if (c == Keys.F1.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
                } else if (c == Keys.F2.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F2);
                } else if (c == Keys.F3.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F3);
                } else if (c == Keys.F4.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
                } else if (c == Keys.F5.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F5);
                } else if (c == Keys.F6.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F6);
                } else if (c == Keys.F7.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F7);
                } else if (c == Keys.F8.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F8);
                } else if (c == Keys.F9.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F9);
                } else if (c == Keys.F10.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
                } else if (c == Keys.F11.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
                } else if (c == Keys.F12.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
                } else if (c == Keys.META.charAt(0)) {
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
//                } else if (c == Keys.COMMAND.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COMMAND);
//                } else if (c == Keys.ZENKAKU_HANKAKU.charAt(0)) {
//                  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ZENKAKU_HANKAKU);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a concise way to release a chorded control key; [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496445/59087).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a workaround solution.

I don't know if it affects other things or not, but it works fine for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```